# Net.HttpClient Cancel ReadAsStringAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I use `SendAsync` with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` to get the headers first. Next I check the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` to make sure the response is markup and the size is decent. I use a `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel the `SendAsync` if it exceeds a certain timespan.

But then, if the type and size are correct, I continue to actually fetch the markup string with `ReadAsStringAsync`. **Can I add a cancellation token to this call?** So if the actual download takes too long, I can abort it. Or can this be done in any other way?

I don't want to use `GetStringAsync` as I use a custom `HttpRequestMessage`.

***PS***: I'm rather new to C#, 2 weeks. Something might be eluding me.

Comment: Does `ReadAsStringAsync()` actually continue to block if you use your existing `CancellationTokenSource` and/or dispose of your `HttpContent` object? It looks as if `ReadAsStringAsync()` is designed to never actually need a cancellation token, because the operation will *already* get cancelled when appropriate. (But I can't actually try it right now, so I don't know if this is right, and if it is, which of the two approaches works.)

Comment: @hvd I use `CancellationToken` in `SendAsync` but I use the flag to just fetch headers first. Content is *(should not be)* fetched until I use `ReadAsStringAsync()`. So in HTTP, first step reads the headers, second read the actual data stream. I'd like to cancel inside the data stream without leaving dangling Tasks.

Comment: I understand that. I'm trying to say that it seems like that second operation can already be cancelled, without having to send a second cancellation token, but that I don't see *exactly* how. If you can't get something working from my comment, I'll test when I get the chance, but that won't be today.

Comment: @hvd I'm current using `WithCancellation` mentioned in the answer. But this leaves dangling tasks. I will test to see if the `SendAsync` cancellation token still works in the `ReadAsStringAsync` but I need to setup a specialized test case. So I'll write a local web server to send content back very slow so I can cancel before it's all sent...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now available in .NET 5:

```
ReadAsStringAsync(CancellationToken)
```

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpContent_ReadAsStringAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. There's [no overload of `ReadAsStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts a cancellation token and you [can't cancel a non-cancelable async operation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx).

You can however abandon that operation and move on with a `WithCancellation` extension method, which won't actually cancel the operation but will let the code flow as if it has been:

```
static Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return task.IsCompleted
        ? task
        : task.ContinueWith(
            completedTask => completedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
            cancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Comment: Noticed that comment also. Trying it now but not too happy to leave the `Tasks` afloat... `ReadString()` implies multiple socket reads until the entire response is fetched. It should have `CancellationToken` support as it has the chance to cancel between those reads.

Comment: I found in a UWP app that if an exception occurred in the wrapped task, it wasn't picked up by the code awaiting on the `WithCancellation` task. The program terminated with an unhandled exception.

Comment: @EdwardBrey `UnobservedTaskException` I assume. Yes, it's important to always `await` tasks or otherwise check if they resulted in an exception. I learned that the exact same way, with a Windows App. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK to use the big hammer, you can dispose the HttpClient, which will shut everything down. Unlike just abandoning the unwanted call to GetStringAsync, this avoids wasting network resources, which speeds up other operations (possibly including whatever your next operation will be).

Comment: On second thought, this might not be correct. It depends on the scope of cancelation for HttpClient, which isn't documented. I [created an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6628) to clarify.

Comment: I had the same idea, but i didn't work. (.NET 5)